# Iterate over own container in powershell

Tags: powershell

Does somebody know something about iterators in powershell? When I was implementing simple container class in this language, I found an issue. One of my class members is an array looks like `hidden [String[]] $array= @()`.
I would like to allow users to iterate over my container by simple use of ForEach object. As you know C++, Python and other many languages provide iterators to achieve that. I have looked for "iterator in powershell" or "iterate over own class object in power shell" in documentation, but I nothing have found. Any ideas?

Comment: `class MyClass : Collections.IEnumerable { hidden [String[]] $array = 1..10; [Collections.IEnumerator] GetEnumerator() { return $this.array.GetEnumerator() } }`

Comment: It works man! Thanks a lot.